# Python/Pygame: draw phase drawing too many cards

Tags: python, list, function, pygame, append

I am making a card game, and there is a draw phase which is coded as such:

```
def drawPhase():
    drawHand = hand
    drawDeck = deck
    oppDrawHand = oppHand
    oppDrawDeck = oppDeck
    drawHand.append(drawDeck[0])
    oppDrawHand.append(oppDrawDeck[0])
    for cards in range(2):
        del drawDeck[0]
        del oppDrawDeck[0]
    return drawHand, drawDeck, oppDrawHand, oppDrawDeck
```

I have it appending the list for each hand only once, but for some reason it seems to be drawing four cards for each player and I can't figure it out.  The other parts of the code don't seem relevant for drawing cards but I can post the gameloop if the problem isn't apparent int he function shown earlier.  Thanks!

edit: here is the game loop:

```
while True:
    # defining image indexes
    currentHandImageIndex = None
    endButtonIndex = None

    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    #game loop variables
    hand = playerHand
    oppHand = oppGetHand
    deck = playerDeck
    oppDeck = oppGetDeck
    benchHand = []
    oppBench = []
    postHand = []
    oppPost = []
    perimeterHand = []
    oppPerimet = []
    showHand = displayHand(hand, oppHand)
    handImages = updateHandImages()


    #stage variables
    step = defStep
    isDrawPhase = False

    #text_prompt_choose_for_bench.draw_text()
    endButtonPressed = False    
    mouseClick = False

    #text drawing
    if len(step) == 1:
        isDrawPhase = True
        text_prompt_enter_draw_phase.draw_text()
    if len(step) == 2:
        isBenchPhase = True
        text_prompt_choose_for_bench.draw_text()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            terminate()
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                terminate()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mouseClick = True

    for i, rect in enumerate(HAND_RECTS):

        if rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            currentHandImageIndex = i
            break

    for i, rect in enumerate(END_RECT):

        if rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            endButtonIndex = i
            break

    if mouseClick == True:
        if endButtonIndex is not None:
            endButtonPressed = True
        if currentHandImageIndex is not None:
            if currentHandImageIndex <= len(hand)-1:
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(handImages[currentHandImageIndex], (925,200))

    if isDrawPhase == True:
        if endButtonPressed == True:
            hand, deck = drawPhase()[0], drawPhase()[1]
            oppHand, oppDeck = drawPhase()[2], drawPhase()[3]
            endButtonPressed = False
            isDrawPhase = False
            step.append(1)
            drawPlayMat()
```

Comment: There's too much code missing to debug this. We need a [mcve].

Comment: At the very least, we need to see how this function is called and how you use the results.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to this.  I added the gameloop, hopefully it helps provide context

Answer (score 0):

```
drawHand.append(drawDeck[0])
oppDrawHand.append(oppDrawDeck[0])
for cards in range(2):
    del drawDeck[0]
    del oppDrawDeck[0]
```

This code adds one card to your hand but removes **two** cards from your deck, and the same with your opponent's hand and deck.  This doesn't seem right.

Comment: This is true, that's because I originally had it append 2 cards but it kept adding 4 so I cut it down to 1, at which point it was appropriately adding 2 cards for some reason.  After I added an opponent hand, it started adding 4 cards again at which point I couldn't figure it out.